# PyQt5 - QTabWidget - How can I have seperate heights for each tab

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qsizepolicy

Example code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'tab_widget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 570)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_29 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_29.setObjectName("label_29")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_29, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_27 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_27.setObjectName("label_27")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_27, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_28 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_28.setObjectName("label_28")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_28, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_14, 12, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 13, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_13, 14, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_17, 15, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_15, 16, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_16, 17, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_20, 18, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_18, 19, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_19, 20, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_23, 21, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_21, 22, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_22, 23, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_26, 24, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_24, 25, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_25, 26, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.label_29.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_27.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_28.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_23.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_21.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_22.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_25.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want each tab height to be as small as possible (something of QSizePolicy for each tab to be Minimux or Fixed).

Edit: I don't want to use QSpacer in each tab. That's not the point.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852391

Comment: I really don't understand the answer at all.

Comment: What don't you understand? QTabWidget is a composite made of QTabBar and QStackedWidget, just apply the same concept.

Comment: May I have a full working example please?

Comment: I have made one, check for performance!!!

Answer (score -1):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'tab_widget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 576)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = CustomTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_29 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_29.setObjectName("label_29")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_29, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_27 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_27.setObjectName("label_27")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_27, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_28 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_28.setObjectName("label_28")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_28, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_14, 12, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 13, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_13, 14, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_17, 15, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_15, 16, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_16, 17, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_20, 18, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_18, 19, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_19, 20, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_23, 21, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_21, 22, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_22, 23, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_26, 24, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_24, 25, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_25, 26, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        #spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.MainWindow = MainWindow
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.updateSize)
        self.updateSize()

    def updateSize(self):
        self.tabWidget.updateGeometry()
        self.MainWindow.updateGeometry()
        self.MainWindow.adjustSize()
        self.MainWindow.setFixedHeight(self.centralwidget.sizeHint().height())

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.label_29.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_27.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_28.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_23.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_21.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_22.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_25.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


class CustomTabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        if self.count() < 0:
            return super().sizeHint()

        baseSize = self.currentWidget().sizeHint().expandedTo(
            self.currentWidget().minimumSize())
        if not self.tabBar().isHidden():
            tabHint = self.tabBar().sizeHint()
            if self.tabPosition() in (self.North, self.South):
                baseSize.setHeight(baseSize.height()
                    + tabHint.height())
            else:
                baseSize.setWidth(baseSize.width()
                    + tabHint.width())

        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTabWidgetFrame()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        return self.style().sizeFromContents(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.CT_TabWidget, opt, baseSize, self)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please improve this answer as it provides no explanation about the concepts behind its solution. While it "works", its code also has many issues, starting from the problem that it "suggests" that editing pyuic files is "fine" (which is *not*, and you should know that suggesting that approach is bad without any proper reason or sufficient warning), and continuing with the fact that there is no explanation about how this works and why. Besides, creating so many child widgets is completely pointless: just add a widget that has a different size hint, so that the example easily clarifies itself.